# changing an action link to an image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How could I change an action link `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id_tache })` to an image. I'm just starting with asp .net mvc. (i want to display an image instead of text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a regular link:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(...)"><img src="Url.Content("~/...")" alt="..." /></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small hack

```
@Html.ActionLink("Button Name", "Index", null, new { @class="classname" })
```

and then create a class in your stylesheet

```
a.classname
{
 background: url(../Images/image.gif) no-repeat top left;
 display: block;
 text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */
 }
```