# using images in webgrid links

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

How can I change the action links in this webgrid into images? ps: I want all the images to appear in the same column

```
@{
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage:true ,canSort:true, rowsPerPage :6);
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid", htmlAttributes: new { id = "datatable" },
    headerStyle: "Header",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column(header: "", format: (item) =>
 new HtmlString(
       Html.ActionLink("Détails", "Details", new { id = item.id_client }).ToString() +
       Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Edit", new { id = item.id_client }).ToString() +
                Html.ActionLink("Supprimer", "Delete", new { id = item.id_client }).ToString()
 ), style: "actions"),
    grid.Column("Nom"),
    grid.Column("Prenom", "Prénom"),
    grid.Column("Email")));


                    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing an action link to an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738893/changing-an-action-link-to-an-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add css for hyplerlink to have a background image like this

**Example:**

```
a.bgImg
{
    background: url(../Images/background.gif)
}
```